# How to install AMD-GPU-PRO Drivers in Ubuntu 21.04?

Tags: drivers, graphics, 21.04, amdgpu-pro

Every time I execute

```
./amdgpu-pro-install --opencl=pal,legacy
```

within the

```
amdgpu-pro-21.10-1247438-ubuntu-20.04
```

folder, it will try to install it, but then it will crash with the error:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 amdgpu-dkms
 amdgpu
 amdgpu-pro
 amdgpu-pro-lib32
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
Please Help, thanks.
```

### Things I've tried:

- [This Tutorial](https://tutorialforlinux.com/2021/01/25/step-by-step-amdgpu-pro-ubuntu-21-04-installation-guide/2/), but they say "this setup is Not granted for every
  Linux Kernel so do it at your own Risk", and then they don't specify
  the Kernel they used.
- `sudo dpkg --configure -a`
- booting with `5.8.0-55-generic` Kernel (I only have `5.11.0-18-generic` and `5.8.0-55-generic` installed)

[Full output from the install script](https://pastebin.pl/view/15994842), [Mirror](https://pastebin.com/Gq0G072u)

```
tweimann@lol:$ neofetch 
tweimann@lol 
OS: Ubuntu 21.04 x86_64 
Kernel: 5.11.0-18-generic 
Uptime: 21 mins 
Packages: 4019 (dpkg), 16 (flatpak), 32 (snap) 
Shell: bash 5.1.4 
Resolution: 2560x1440, 1920x1080, 1440x2560 
DE: GNOME 3.38.4 
WM: Mutter 
WM Theme: Adwaita 
Theme: Adwaita-dark [GTK2/3] 
Icons: Yaru [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: gnome-terminal 
CPU: Intel i7-9700K (8) @ 4.900GHz 
GPU: Intel CoffeeLake-S GT2 [UHD Graphics 630] 
GPU: AMD ATI Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590 
Memory: 6698MiB / 63219MiB
```

Please Help, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

> amd release notes: For Ubuntu 20.04.1, only Kernel 5.4/5.6 are supported. Latest Kernel version 5.8+ is not supported. Customers with Kernel 5.8+, need to downgrade to 5.4/5.6 for proper driver support.

it seems that you will have to downgrade to a lower kernel version

Answer (score 3):

Worked for me:

If you are comfortable with an older kernel on your system:

Add repository for old kernel, e.g. former repository from Groovy Gorilla:

```
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ groovy main restricted
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ groovy-updates main restricted
```

Installed Kernel 5.8 + Modules + Headers:

```
apt install linux-image-5.8.0-53-generic linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-53-generic linux-headers-5.8.0-53-generic
```

Changed VERSION_ID in /etc/os-release back to 20.04:

```
root@localhost /e/apt# cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="21.04 (Hirsute Hippo)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 21.04"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=hirsute
UBUNTU_CODENAME=hirsute
```

Change into extracted drivers directory, e.g. in Downloads:

```
cd ~/Downloads/amdgpu-pro-20.50-1234664-ubuntu-20.04
```

Run the installer:

```
./amdgpu-pro-install --opencl=rocr,legacy -y
```

Reboot.

Then, with xrandr you should be able to see the freesync parameters:

```
[user@localhost]➜ ~ xrandr --props | grep free
 freesync_capable: 0 
 freesync: 0 
 freesync_capable: 0 
 freesync: 0
```

Depending on your monitors connection (here: DisplayPort-0) you may be able to change freesync to 1:

```
[user@localhost]➜ ~ xrandr --output DisplayPort-0 --set "freesync" 1
[user@localhost]➜ ~ xrandr --props | grep free
 freesync_capable: 0 
 freesync: 1
 freesync_capable: 0 
 freesync: 0
```

Answer (score 3):

amdgpu-pro-21.30-1290604-ubuntu-20.04
installs and works in 21.04 with kernel 5.11.0-25 after only:

> Changed VERSION_ID in /etc/os-release back to 20.04:

tested in blender 2.93.2

Comment: not for me. I get `error: Detected X Server version 'XServer _64a' is not supported. Supported versions are X.Org 6.9 or later, up to XServer 1.10 (default:v2:x86_64:lib32:XServer _64a:none:5.13.0-7614-generic:)
`